# Add data from one matrix to another based on column name and row name

Tags: r, matrix

If I have two matrices:
A larger empty one containing many rows and columns & a smaller one containing a subset of the rows/columns of the larger one, how can I combine the two so that values from the smaller one are added to the larger one

Creating Data

```
my_matrix <- matrix(nrow =7, ncol = 7)
rownames(my_matrix) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
colnames(my_matrix) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')

my_matrix2 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rownames(my_matrix2) <- c('c', 'e', 'g')
colnames(my_matrix2) <- c('c', 'e', 'g')

my_matrix
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
a NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
d NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
e NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
g NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

 my_matrix2
  c e g
c 1 4 7
e 2 5 8
g 3 6 9
```

```
my_matrix
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
a NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA  1 NA  4 NA  7
d NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
e NA NA  2 NA  5 NA  8
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
g NA NA  3 NA  6 NA  9
```

I can do it using a combination of `reshape2::melt()`, `tidyverse` & `reshape2::acast()` but was wondering if there was a more efficient way of managing this as I have to do similar for a very large dataset? Thanks

Current Approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

my_matrix_df <- melt(my_matrix) 
my_matrix_df2 <- melt(my_matrix2)

tets <- my_matrix_df %>%
  left_join(., my_matrix_df2, by=c('Var1', 'Var2')) %>%
  mutate(
    value = case_when(!is.na(value.y) ~ value.y)
  ) %>% select(1,2,5)

acast(tets,  Var1 ~ Var2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the row and column names in the indexing.

```r
> my_matrix[rownames(my_matrix2), colnames(my_matrix2)] <- my_matrix2
> my_matrix
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
a NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
b NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
c NA NA  1 NA  4 NA  7
d NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
e NA NA  2 NA  5 NA  8
f NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
g NA NA  3 NA  6 NA  9
```

Comment: This is why I love R. Pure elegance.